# Delphi optimisation : constant loop

Tags: performance, delphi, for-loop, optimization, compiler-optimization

I just noticed something quite interesting in a program I'm writing.  I have a simple procedure that populates a TStringlist with objects of type x.

I added a breakpoint as I was tracing an issue and stumbled across this ans was hoping someone might be able to explain why it is happening, or link to a relevant document as I couldn't find anything.

My loop goes from 0 - 11.  The pointer that I'm using was initialised in the loop by for nPtr := 0 but when the program was run the nPtr var was going from 12 down to 1.  I then initialised the var outside the loop as shown in the code snippet but the same thing happened.  The variable is used nowhere else in the unit.

I asked one of the guys I worked with who said it was due to Delphi optimisation but I'd like to know why and how it decides which loop should be affected.

Thanks for any help.

Code:

```
procedure TUnit.ProcedureName;
var
    nPtr : Integer;
    obj : TObject;
begin
nPtr:=0;//added later
for nPtr := 0 to 11 do
    begin
    obj := TObject.Create(Self);
    slPeriodList.AddObject('X', obj);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: It's a limitation (or bug, depending on how harsh you are) in the debugger. David explains in his answer what the compiler is doing, which is fine, but IMHO the debugger should really know that this transformation has been performed and reverse (eliminate) the observable effect for watch variables, and so on. Alas, it does not.

Comment: ISTM that it is too much asked from the debugger. It either displays the ominous message that "nPtr is not accessible due to optimization" or it displays the real value, showing you what went on under the hood. I prefer the latter (and that is what it does now). It is not the debugger's task to make it look as if the loop index goes up if it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The optimization is only possible if the loop body does not refer to the loop variable. In that case, if the lower bound of the loop is zero, then the compiler will reverse the loop.

If the loop variable is never referenced by the loop body then the compiler is justified in implementing the loop however it pleases. All it is required to do is execute the loop body as many times as is mandated by the loop bounds. Indeed, the compiler would be perfectly justified in optimizing away the loop variable.

Consider this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure Test1;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 11 do
    Writeln(0);
end;

procedure Test2;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 11 do
    Writeln(i);
end;

begin
  Test1;
  Test2;
end.
```

The body of `Test1` is compiled to this code by XE7, 32 bit Windows compiler, with release options:

```
Project1.dpr.9: for i := 0 to 11 do
00405249 BB0C000000       mov ebx,$0000000c
Project1.dpr.10: Writeln(0);
0040524E A114784000       mov eax,[$00407814]
00405253 33D2             xor edx,edx
00405255 E8FAE4FFFF       call @Write0Long
0040525A E8D5E7FFFF       call @WriteLn
0040525F E800DBFFFF       call @_IOTest
Project1.dpr.9: for i := 0 to 11 do
00405264 4B               dec ebx
00405265 75E7             jnz $0040524e
```

The compiler is running the loop downwards, as can be seen by the use of `dec`. Notice that the test for loop termination is performed with `jnz` with no need for a `cmp`. That is because `dec` performs an implicit compare against zero.

The documentation for `dec` says the following:

> **Flags Affected**
>
> The CF flag is not affected. The OF, SF, ZF, AF, and PF flags are set
>   according to the result.

The `ZF` flag is set if and only if the result of the `dec` instruction is zero. And the `ZF` is what determines whether or not `jnz` branches.

The code emitted for `Test2` is:

```
Project1.dpr.17: for i := 0 to 11 do
0040526D 33DB             xor ebx,ebx
Project1.dpr.18: Writeln(i);
0040526F A114784000       mov eax,[$00407814]
00405274 8BD3             mov edx,ebx
00405276 E8D9E4FFFF       call @Write0Long
0040527B E8B4E7FFFF       call @WriteLn
00405280 E8DFDAFFFF       call @_IOTest
00405285 43               inc ebx
Project1.dpr.17: for i := 0 to 11 do
00405286 83FB0C           cmp ebx,$0c
00405289 75E4             jnz $0040526f
```

Note that the loop variable is increasing, and we now have an extra `cmp` instruction, executed on every loop iteration.

It is perhaps interesting to note that the 64 bit Windows compiler does not include this optimization. For `Test1` it produces this:

```
Project1.dpr.9: for i := 0 to 11 do
00000000004083A5 4833DB           xor rbx,rbx
Project1.dpr.10: Writeln(0);
00000000004083A8 488B0D01220000   mov rcx,[rel $00002201]
00000000004083AF 4833D2           xor rdx,rdx
00000000004083B2 E839C3FFFF       call @Write0Long
00000000004083B7 4889C1           mov rcx,rax
00000000004083BA E851C7FFFF       call @WriteLn
00000000004083BF E86CB4FFFF       call @_IOTest
00000000004083C4 83C301           add ebx,$01
Project1.dpr.9: for i := 0 to 11 do
00000000004083C7 83FB0C           cmp ebx,$0c
00000000004083CA 75DC             jnz Test1 + $8
```

I'm not sure why this optimization has not been implemented in the 64 bit compiler. My guess would be that the optimization has negligible effect in real world cases and the designers chose not to expend effort implementing it for the 64 bit compiler.

Comment: `The optimization is only possible if the loop body does not refer to the loop variable`. That is not quite true. It is only possible if the order in which the loop variable is accessed is unimportant for the result, i.e. it has no visible side effects and the final result is the same. So `for I := 0 to 9 do A[I] := 0;` does refer to the loop variable in the loop, but it has no visible side effects and it does not change the result if it runs backward.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That would also require `A` to be a local variable that has not been captured. What you see is fair. I don't think the compiler analyses anything like that in practise. And we don't actually have anything formal like the C/C++ "as-if" rule.

Comment: But I agree that in the real world, its effect is probably negligible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `A` can be any array or pointer. The end effect is the same, whether the loop runs down or up.

Comment: If `A` is visible outside the loop, then the order matters. Being visible outside the loop makes the loop body execution order observable. So if `A` was a global variable then the compiler would unable to prove that re-ordering the loop execution did not change observable behaviour.

Comment: @Rudy and David, FWIW, in such simple references to array elements, the compiler precalculates the address of the first affected element and then `add` (or `sub` in `downto` loops) according to element size. IOW, it doesn't even use the loop control variable for indexing to the array.

Comment: @TomBrunberg That's not really what we are talking about

Comment: It used to use pointers indeed, and increment or decrement these, but current indexing modes are actually easier to handle and fast enough. Especially if you must do something like `C[I] := A[I] and B[I];` indexing is in fact faster and easier than updating 3 pointers each time.

Comment: Yes it was, the order of array element access is the correct one despite the control variable calculating down or up.

Comment: If the loop uses pointers, then it is extremely hard for the debugger to show a useful index. <g>

Comment: @TomBrunberg Rudy is saying that the compiler could, in principle, implement `for I := 0 to 9 do A[I] := 0;` by zeroising the elements in any order. I am saying that is so provided that `A` is not observable outside the loop body.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Also, I've never come across this pointer array access code that you hint at. I'm used to seeing x86 indexed access operations, or explicitly calculated offsets for element sizes that don't have hardware supported access instructions. Could you provide a code sample which leads to the type of code you describe?

Comment: David, if Rudy says the elements are accessed in any other order than the loop describes, then that is something I have never seen.

Comment: @TomBrunberg He isn't saying that. He is saying that the compiler is justified in making whatever transformations it desires so long as the observable behaviour is not altered. Essentially the C/C++ **as-if** rule. Not that we have anything formally written down like that in Delphi because there is no standard, and incomplete documentation.

Comment: David, this is what I talk about: MainFormU.pas.122: for x := 2 to 3 do
005E4B24 BA02000000       mov edx,$00000002
005E4B29 B87C975F00       mov eax,$005f977c
MainFormU.pas.123: arr[x*2] := 99;
005E4B2E C70063000000     mov [eax],$00000063
005E4B34 83C008           add eax,$08
MainFormU.pas.122: for x := 2 to 3 do
005E4B37 4A               dec edx
005E4B38 75F4             jnz $005e4b2e
MainFormU.pas.124: end;
005E4B3A C3               ret 
. edx is the loop counter, eax is precalculated to point to the first affected element, then just modified by add aex, $08 ($08 because of [x*2].

Comment: @Tom OK, I can see that. The compiler has optimised away the loop variable because it is simply not needed. And it also arranges loop termination by counting down to 0 and so avoiding a `cmp`. That's not what we were talking about though.

Comment: I think you're all talking about the same thing. I will assert that in this array-zeroing scenario you're talking about, `A[9]` will *never* be initialized before `A[0]` when the source code says the loop index goes from 0 to 9. The debugger may say that the value of `i` starts at 9 and goes down to 0, but the values in the array will be set in exactly the order the source code says. And the reason it happens that way is as @Tom demonstrated, where the compiler increments a pointer and decrements a counter. The compiler does no data-flow analysis to determine external observability.

Comment: @Rob No. Well, what you say is true that in Tom's example asm, the values are assigned in ascending order. But Rudy was saying that the compiler could, if it chose to do so, assign in some other order. Nobody said it would ever do so. Just that it could. Look carefully at the quote that Rudy highlighted in his very first comment.

Comment: I see. You and Rudy are talking hypothetically. In the lingo, you're saying a *sufficiently smart compiler* may assign `A` in varying orders. But Delphi is not sufficiently smart, and it never has been. The optimization you're talking about is one that would be sound for Delphi to perform, if anyone managed to program it to do so. I assumed you were talking about something the compiler *actually does*. (When others have discussed this before, they assume the compiler behaves as Rudy described, but it's actually only what Tom showed.)

Comment: @Rob Yes that's how I was talking. I think Rudy was also. The point I made to Rudy was that the hypothetical compiler could only make that transformation if A was sufficiently local that the compiler could prove it was not observable from elsewhere.